# Piped commands return code without bash&PIPESTATUS

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, pipe, busybox

i have a limited busybox unit that has only /bin/sh so no bash and no PIPESTATUS

Trying to run a command:

```
upgrade.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log.log | udplogger
```

Now i need to get the exit code of upgrade.sh to continue further with additional upgrades or to stop.

Any idea how ? On bash you have pipestatus where i can get result of first command but with only /bin/sh i have no idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with executing that pipeline in a subshell, you can use redirections like this:

```
{ status=$(
  { { upgrade.sh 2>&1
      echo $? >&3
    } | tee -a log.log | udplogger >&4
  } 3>&1 )
} 4>&1
echo $status
```

Comment: YEAH :) Works :) THANK YOU!

Comment: How to output to stdout during execution of the script ?

Comment: @Lonko not following. what do you mean?

Comment: right now based on your answer i dont get any console output from the script... everything is in the log.log but nothing on console. Additionally is is possible to output the script output as they happen ?

Comment: @Lonko With your original script, do you get any output on the console? `tee`'s output goes to `udplogger`, and `udplogger`'s output is written to stdout in both mine and yours

Comment: Sorry you are correct. Is there a way to output to stdout as the script outputs ? now it outputs when the script completes

Comment: @Lonko I don't know of any.

Answer (score 1):

Can you split the stream?

```
up_out=$(upgrade.sh 2>&1)
up_status=$1
echo "${up_out}" | tee -a log.log | udplogger
echo "${up_status}"
```

Alternative:
Use special functions:

```
store() { echo $? > pipestatus; }
popup() { cat; status=$(cat pipestatus); rm pipestatus; return "${status}"; }
```

Demo:

```
touch strange_file
{ rm strange_file 2>&1 ; store; } | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' | popup ; echo "$?"
{ rm strange_file 2>&1 ; store; } | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' | popup ; echo "$?"
```

Output:

```
0
RM: CANNOT REMOVE 'STRANGE_FILE': NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY
1
```

In your case:

```
{ upgrade.sh 2>&1; store; } | tee -a log.log | udplogger | popup
```

and use `$?`.

Comment: pipestatus is not available in /bin/sh othervise i would use pipestatus[0] or similar

Comment: pipestatus a my random temporary filename, not the bash variable. `store()` saves the exitcode in the file, `popup()` reads the file and uses the value as its exit status. When you have different streams, you need different filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Error handling can be done this way:

```
fifo=/tmp/upgrade.sh.fifo
mkfifo $fifo
tee -a log.log < $fifo | udplogger &

if  upgrade.sh 2>&1; then
    echo Carry on >&2
else
    echo Stop >&2
fi > $fifo
rm $fifo
```

**Updated** upon comment from oguz ismail